# I'm trying to click on search button but it is not clicked,and I didn't get any exception in console

Tags: selenium-webdriver, click

here I have "select" drop down and "search" option ,and I have one 
    "search" button, when i enter the data into drop down and search option 
    then i need to click on search button..but search button is not clicking 
    here and no exception is displayed in console..so searched data is not 
    displaying..

```java
//finding the "Select" drop down element
Select data=new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("driverKeyName")));
data.selectByVisibleText("Driver Name");

//finding the "Search" field element
driver.findElement(By.name("driverValue")).sendKeys("Malveena");

//finding the "search" button element
WebDriverWait wait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("assignVechile")));
```

I need to click on Search Button.

html code

```html
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" name="Save" id="assignVechile">
```

For login:

in this "Add Driver" button also I got same issuse

Comment: Please provide more information. Need html code snippet for problem section.

Comment: Need more clarification on html part of login page. If you can edit question description and provide login page/frame html code snippet would help!

Comment: for login i gave you code above please check

Comment: Please don't post code in comments, you can [edit] your question and format code properly

Answer (score 0):

I have checked, When you click the Driver management link. There is a loader which stops the driver to interact with underlaying elements.

You need to add wait after clicking driver management link.
Just for testing purpose use thread.sleep(20) after clicking driver management link.

loader div has an attribute **style="visibility:hidden ;"**
You can also use an explicit wait where driver only proceed when style attribute is **style="visibility:hidden ;"**

Comment: increase the time to 50 may be your net is slow. Also try to debug the page and how much time loader is taking.

Comment: Means your test is passing but not clicking the button ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195041/discussion-between-waqar-nadir-and-divya-u).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195047/discussion-between-divya-u-and-waqar-nadir).